# Bash script to create a symlink is adding the characters ._ in my variable to create a symlink

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink

I'm using the below bash script to randomly choose a .mp4 file and symlink it to another folder that the application (Plex) can read. The problem is that there seems to be (randomly) a "._" added in the variable $FILE that is then used in the symlink. Any ideas?

## Script

```bash
#/bin/sh
rm -f /media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ/preroll.mp4
find /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/ -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | sort -R | tail -1 | while read FILE; do
ln -s "$FILE" /media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ/preroll.mp4 ;
done
```

### Symlink check

Just look at the end of every 4th line.
See `._PlexStrangerThingsPreroll.mp4` then `._PlexSnowPreroll.mp4` again `._Plex preroll 6F.mp4`

The ._ should not appear there.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Apr 10 13:19 preroll.mp4 -> /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._PlexStrangerThingsPreroll.mp4
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Apr 10 13:23 preroll.mp4 -> /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._PlexSnowPreroll.mp4
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Apr 10 13:24 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex preroll 8F.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 66 Apr 10 13:24 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex Preroll-Fallout4-1080-12.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Apr 10 13:25 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex preroll 6F.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Apr 10 13:25 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex Preroll energy reveal.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62 Apr 10 13:26 preroll.mp4 -> /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/PlexStrangerThingsPreroll.mp4
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Apr 10 13:27 preroll.mp4 -> /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._PlexFirePreroll.mp4
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Apr 10 13:27 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex preroll 6F.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Apr 10 13:28 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex preroll 13E.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Apr 10 13:28 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex Preroll energy reveal.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Apr 10 13:28 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex Preroll energy reveal.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 Apr 10 13:46 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex Preroll-Fallout4-1080-12.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Apr 10 13:50 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex preroll 6F.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 Apr 10 13:50 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex Preroll-Fallout4-1080-12.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 4.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 68 Apr 10 13:50 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/._Plex Preroll-Fallout4-1080-12.mp4'
root@wyss-server:/media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Apr 10 13:50 preroll.mp4 -> '/media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/Plex preroll 8E.mp4'
```

I'm using ubuntu 18

Comment: Why do you use `bash` tag?

Comment: I would argue that those files do in fact exist in that directory which is why they are being picked up and symlinked. "dot underscore" files are generally files that have been transferred from macos onto a file system that doesn't support MacOS extended attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JNevill you are correct. The files are coming from MacOS to Ubuntu. I did not realize that MacOS creates those hidden files. Whenever I list `ls` files in the directory they do not show.

When I added `-not \( -iname "._*" \)` to the script it ignores those files.

Below is the updated script.

```bash
#/bin/sh
rm -f /media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ/preroll.mp4
find /media/joshua/Media/PlexPrerolls/ -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -not \( -iname "._*" \) | sort -R | tail -1 | while read FILE; $
ln -s "$FILE" /media/PATH_TO_PREROLL_THAT_PLEX_CAN_READ/preroll.mp4 ;
done
```

Also, I forgot to say in my original post that I got this script originally from: https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/arccd7/better_way_to_randomize_plexrolls/

In case someone gets here because of a search engine or something, I've created instructions to implement this script for its intended purpose here: https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/fyoqh4/randomizing_prerolls_on_linux/